# How to enforce bean contract validation in Groovy?

Tags: validation, groovy

I have a POGO that contains two fields:

```
class BaseEntity {
    Long id
    Long version
}
```

Both field **must** be positive (neither 0 nor negative). **What is the minimal amount of code I need to add to prevent `BaseEntity` instances from being created (or set) with non-positive id/version values?**

I *know* I could accomplish this the "old, Java way":

```
class BaseEntity {
    private Long id
    private Long version

    BaseEntity(Long id, Long version) {
        super()

        setId(id)
        setVersion(version)
    }

    Long getId() {
        // Return a "clone" to preserve the original ID
        new Long(id)
    }

    Long getVersion() {
        // Return a "clone" to preserve the original version
        new Long(version)
    }

    def setId(Long id) {
        if(id < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ID must be positive!")
        }

        this.id = id
    }

    def setVersion(Long version) {
        if(version < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be positive!")
        }

        this.version = version
    }
}
```

...but this seems like *a lot* of boilerplate code that the Groovy community *must* have found a shortcut around...

---

**Update**:

I added GContracts per the suggestion and then run the following JUnit test:

```
@Test
void id_cannotBeZero() {
    BaseEntity entity = new BaseEntity()

    entity.id = 0
}
```

When I run this the JUnit passes **without** throwing any kind of exception.

Comment: Have you looked at [GContracts](http://gcontracts.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Using [GContracts](http://gcontracts.org/) like below:

```
@Grab(group='org.gcontracts', module='gcontracts-core', version='[1.2.12,)')
import org.gcontracts.annotations.*

@Invariant({ id > 0 && version > 0 })
class BaseEntity {
    Long id
    Long version
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - however after adding your suggested changes, this doesn't seem to work (see my JUnit test above). The JUnit test passes where (I would think) it would be throwing an exception of some sort...any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Although using `@Requires` [on constructor does the trick](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8404667/). Will look into it more.